# Liquid Template HTML variable

Tags: liquid

is there any filter to render a variable as HTML and not plain text?

```
{% assign htmlcontent = '<h1>hello</h1><br>' %}
{{ htmlcontent }}
```

the Output is then

```
<h1>hello</h1><br>
```

so it will get rendered as plain text and not HTML in the mail

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the filter `escape`.

```
{% assign htmlcontent = '<h1>hello</h1><br>' %}
{{ htmlcontent | escape }}
```

I have this page in the bookmarks: https://www.shopify.com/ca/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet. It's always useful.